# How remove white space from template literals when stored in an object?

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I'm creating a boilerplate project with node.

At its most basic when I run `node create.js projectName` I want to create a project folder with a bunch of assets.

This is a snippet of the code:

```
function data(){
    return {
        'index.html': `<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
        ...
        <body> <script src="myscripts/main.js"></script> </body>
        </html>`,
    }
}
```

Then I create the file

```
fs.writeFileSync(`${p[0]}/index.html`, data()['index.html'])
```

I removed a lot of irrelevant code but, the point in the generated `index.html` looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        ...
        <body> <script src="myscripts/main.js"></script> </body>
        </html>
```

How can I remove that white space at the beginning of lines 2-5 **without "uglyfying" the I'm writing the object inside the `data` function**?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove whitespace at the beginning of the lines with a regular expression.

```
fs.writeFileSync(`${p[0]}/index.html`, data()['index.html'].replace(/^\s+/gm, '');
```

The `m` flag makes `^` match newlines in the middle of the input string, rather than just the beginning of the string.

Another option is to use the desired indentation in the template literal.

```
function data(){
  return {
    'index.html': `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
    ...
  </head>
  <body> <script src="myscripts/main.js"></script> </body>
</html>`,
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem like "unglifying" it.

Comment: That's more like it. Thanks, is there a way to keep some of the indentations though? If you have a look at what I just added, for example under the `<html lang="en">` tag you'd have a `link` to style sheet, which would be indented/nested. But this is great non the less.

Comment: If you want the indentation to match the HTML tag nesting level, that would be really complicated. Why don't you just put the desired nesting in the template literal in the first place? Why do you consider that "uglifying" it, since it will look right in the code.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm going to end up doing but I just thought I could get that effect whilst keeping the object looking "clean"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function replace(str) {
         return str.replace(/^([ ]*)/gim, "");
    }
```

[CheckThis](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GHAKYJCB9QYH)